# Поиск по условию и вывод из вектора

Tags: c++, c++builder, vector

Есть `vector<string> words;` со словами, взятыми из файла.

Необходимо организовать вывод одного из слов, начинающихся на введённую пользователем букву. При следующем запросе пользователя программа должна выводить одно из неиспользованных ранее слов, и если их не осталось, сообщать об этом.

Как реализовать?

Comment: Что такое "неиспользованных"? Непросмотренных? Или невыведенных?

Comment: Не выведенных, если угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Ищите с начала - `find(words.begin(),words.end(),...)`. Если нашли - сохраните итератор, выводите найденное слово. При следующем поиске начинайте искать с итератора, следующего за сохраненным.

Если `find` вернет итератор `words.end()` - сообщайте, что все слова найдены...

Comment: Логично. Но в таком случае будут каждый раз выводиться слова в одной и той же последовательности. Хочется избежать этого.

Comment: Покажите в вашем исходном вопросе слово "случайно". Или хотя бы что вы будете делать несколько запросов. Без четкого ТЗ результат один - ХЗ. Вам могу посоветовать, например, перед началом очередной серии применять [`shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)... Решение зависит от того, что можно делать с исходными данными, а что нельзя.